# JQuery .replace function overlapping similar phrases

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery .replace function to turn all occurrences of certain words into links using this code:

```
$.each($('p'), function(i,e) {
  $(e).html($(e).html().replace(/candy/g,'<a href="http://www.rantlifestyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/First.jpg">candy</a>'));
})
```

The problem is that some of the phrases contain the same letters, so when I have two that conflict, the words don't get replaced correctly. For instance, if I used this code as well as the code above:

```
    $.each($('p'), function(i,e) {
      $(e).html($(e).html().replace(/can/g,'<a href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/empty-tin-can-7151872.jpg">can</a>'));
})
```

Then it tries to replace the letters 'candy' *and* 'can' with each link I've specified in the one occurrence of the word 'candy.'

Is there a way to specify that I want the replace function to work with specific phrases?

Side note, I tried to make a [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/cleo_not_chloe/bndeL2q6/) of this on jsfiddle and it's not working. Maybe that has something to do with my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not working on your fiddle because you don't have jquery included on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you need to use this to match whole words:

```
$.each($('p'), function(i,e) {
  $(e).html($(e).html().replace(/\bcandy\b/,'<a href="http://www.rantlifestyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/First.jpg">candy</a>'));
})

    $.each($('p'), function(i,e) {
      $(e).html($(e).html().replace(/\bcan\b/,'<a href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/empty-tin-can-7151872.jpg">can</a>'));
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bndeL2q6/2/

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know if there's a way you can find letters next to numbers? Like if there were A's throughout the document, but they were all A1, A4, A6, A20, etc. Could you still find those A's and link them?

Comment: You can do anything with regular expressions. To be honest, they're not really my strong suite. I'm sure the answer i out there, though!

Comment: I understand. If you could even suggest a phrase to search for, it would really help me out! I didn't even know these were called regular expressions!

Comment: You can search something like "search for character before digit regex" or "find string before number regex" something like that. I'm messing around with it right now, I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Regular expressions are a necessary evil in the world of programming. With great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Okay, you've been so helpful, and I have another question (I'd move this to chat but my account is too new, I guess). The code won't allow more than one occurrence of a word in a <p> to be replaced. Do you know why that is? https://jsfiddle.net/cleo_not_chloe/bndeL2q6/5/